# Exception generated while accessing value from AnyObject

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, anyobject

This kind of error is generated

> [_SwiftValue objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000a805a0

When I run the below code

```
 let obvj = object as AnyObject
 print(obvj)
 let ct = obvj.object(forKey: "currenttime") as! Date
```

Here value of object is

```
Optional({
    currenttime = "2016-10-14 11:30:12 +0000";
    endtime = "2016-10-14 14:30:12 +0000";
    success = 1;
})
```

While this was working fine in Swift 2.2

Comment: What is the value of object supposed to be? Is it supposed to be a dictionary or array? I put "object = your code" in a playground and it prints as "Optional((Function))".

Comment: @zionperez It is dictionary like above

Comment: Could you give me some feedback on my answer? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated that the `object` variable is a dictionary type. I could be wrong, but I believe your syntax for a dictionary object is not correct. A dictionary should take the format: `[key 1: value 1, key 2: value 2, key 3: value 3]`.

Here is the code I ran successfully in a playground:

```
//: Playground
import Foundation

let object = Optional([
    "currenttime" :  "2016-10-14T11:30:12+00:00",
    "endtime" : "2016-10-14T14:30:12+00:00",
    "success" : 1
])

let obvj = object as AnyObject?
print(obvj) // prints the dictionary object
let ct = obvj!.object(forKey: "currenttime") as! String
print(ct) // prints: 2016-10-14T11:30:12+00:00

// https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/dateformatter    
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)

let date = dateFormatter.date(from: ct)
print(date?.description) // prints: Optional("2016-10-14 11:30:12+0000")
```

The `object` var is initialized as an optional dictionary type.

The line that you have here: `let obvj = object as AnyObject` should be `let obvj = object as AnyObject?`. `object` should be cast as an optional AnyObject because it started as an optional dictionary type.

I'm not sure how your `string as Date` is working. It did not work for me. Maybe you added an extension to Date in your code? In my code above, I used a DateFormatter from the standard library and slightly modified the date string to fit the expected format. I followed the sample from the developer reference "Working With Fixed Format Date Representations" found here:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/dateformatter

Answer (score 1):

Error is saying that your `object` is type of `_SwiftValue` and you cannot access Objective C method with it, to solve your problem cast your `object` as `[String: Any]` and use `subscript` instead of `object(forKey:)`.

```
if let obvj = object as? [String: Any] {
    if let ct = obvj["currenttime"] as? Date

    }
}
```

Comment: I totally get what you said and its correct but my code is such that i need to use AnyObject else i need to change at all places which may be 1000 of changes.

Comment: @ParthAdroja If you doesn't want to use subscript then use `object(forKey:)` with dictionary.